# Resolving personal issues in CS:GO servers

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have recently started paying CS:GO and I don't have much of experience on it. I choose servers with low ping and there is this server with low ping where I play regularly. It runs 24x7 hostedd by some organization.

Here some players are regular and very good ones. Since I am a bad player, they tend to tk me to take away my weapon. Sometimes I am the lone survivor in the end and fail to win the match. So as revenge they tk me as soon as I spawn in next round.

Is there any way I can report this activity in CS:GO?

Comment: Also try playing on official valve servers, and competitive gamemode when you reach profilelevel 3, as everyone on Competitive is on your skilllevel.

Comment: note that TKers are part of "the life" and you should not assume it is because "you suck." In fact telling you you suck as they are TKing you is all part of the script. You can block communication with them via the steam interface and that *may* prevent them from joining the same servers as you. I wish more games had "reflective fire" instead of team fire. if they *really* cared they wouldn't play on PUB teams

Answer (score 1):

Check if they have a forum. Some such organisations have forums and hence admins and mods for the servers and some regulation, but it's highly unlikely. I used to play on a server run by a huge local site and they had many other servers, many admins very popular forum, threads to report abusers etc you could even try to become an admin.

In general strafe away from community servers. In past games there wasn't anything else but here you have Official Match Making. I'd recommend you play that. After few games you will start getting matched against players of similar skills, and generally in MM people tend not to TK or do other kinds of crap because of bans and cool down.

Another option might be paid 3rd party providers like ESEA and such but I personally have never tried them so can't comment on that.

Also, if you are not fan of MM (I personally only play DM to warm up and then go to MM) You can reserach such servers that provide some security, check your country for someone providing cs:go servers and have it mentioned on their site (these will have low ping as well)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off playing on valve official servers once you're more confident with your play, but as a starting point, why not just play offline with bots? You won't have to worry about ping as you'll be playing locally.

Playing offline, you also don't have to worry about team mates, you can simply practice your aim and shooting with the various guns on bots. Bots for most players with a bit of experience are easy to play against, even on the expert bot level.

I would recommend playing offline with bots of the lowest level first and work your way up to expert bots as it becomes easier. Once you find playing against them easy, move on to official servers and play against real players in the various modes.

The casual servers have a wide range of skill groups, so you may feel that you're not ready, but with things like deathmatch you are playing on your own to maximise your kills, so again you don't have to worry about letting your team down. This is also a good place to warm up as stated in the other answer.

Also, there a lots of community made warm up / aim maps that a lot of players use before matches.

**[Aim Botz](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=243702660)**

[image]

**[training_aim_csgo2](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=213240871)**

[image]

**[Fast Aim/Reflex Training Map [SP vs Bot Map] / aimtraindriving](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=368026786)**

[image]

Once you're a bit more confident, I'd suggest competitive mode would best suit you as you'll play with people in a similar skill group to you. You do have to commit to playing the match though, which usually averages any time between 30-60 minutes at the lower skill groups.

To play competitive mode you need to obtain [Level 3 - Private Rank](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224216/what-is-the-fastest-and-easiest-way-to-reach-lvl-3-for-the-private-rank) in their XP system, which can be gained by playing on official servers.

With official server, you're less likely to get team killed. In casual mode, team damage / friendly fire is off and in competitive mode, you get punished for repeatedly killing team mates and you can be reported for griefing.

GLHF